# What does it mean for a set of closed shapes to intersect?

Tags: geometry

To my understanding, a "shape" is a set of points in $n$-dimensional space. *e.g.*, rectangles, triangles, lines, spheres, hyperspheres, *etc.*. For two (or any amount) of shapes to "intersect", the representative sets for these shapes must have points in common.

Here enters my confusion — if two rectangles are touching on a corner, are they said to be intersecting? Is there a difference between "touching" and "intersecting" in Geometry?

To makes things a little more concrete, consider the following example:

$R1$ and $R2$ are defined by the cross products $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}$ and $\hat{-i}\times\hat{-j}$, respectively. $R1$ and $R2$ thus share only 1 point, the origin $[0,0]$. Are $R1$ and $R2$ said to be intersecting?

Comment: This is not standardized terminology. However, in the context of covering problems, *intersect* often means *intersect on a set of positive measure*, which rules out intersecting at a 'corner'. Is your example the one you are actually interested in? If not, it would help to have that extra context, since again, the terminology is not standardized.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks Eric.

Comment: @EricStucky Would your definition suggest that the rectangles $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}$ and $\hat{i}\times\hat{-j}$ intersect? Trying to pin down what you mean by a "set of positive measure"

Comment: Adding to what @EricStucky said, consider perpendicular intersecting rectangles like the ones pictured here: http://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Logo/pixD.png. Context is important - I would say that these shapes intersect, but the shapes have measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and even if the rectangles are viewed as positive-measure sets in a plane, the intersection has measure zero. I would expect any mathematical discussion of these ideas that uses a definition of “intersect” other than the usual one for sets ($R1\cup R2\neq\emptyset$) would provide a clear definition.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the definition, positive measure here means positive area. For example, the area of a shape like a rectangle is a positive number, but a point $(0,0)$ has an area, or measure, of exactly zero.

Comment: @Robert: Your notation for rectangles is not one I've seen before, but, I'm assuming you mean the products of intevals $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times [-1,0]$? In the line of work I do, I do not consider these intersecting. But again, **this is not standardized** and the answer that you want will be dependent on why you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If sets are closed, they contain their boundaries. In a rectangle, this means that the parallel lines that bound the rectangle are included in the rectangle. So the intersection of $R1$ and $R2$ is non-empty, or in other words, they do intersect.

Comment: True. We must consider whether we mean open or closed shapes. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding has always been that 'intersecting' shapes would, in fact, refer to the set of points. If the two (or more) *closed* shapes touch on a corner, that particular point is in the sets representing both (or all) shapes and thus we consider them to intersect.

EDIT: Added that touching corners are only sufficient for closed shapes.

Comment: I added the clarification in the wrong spot. Should be correct now. Thanks.